# Word for "Deeply Saddened by Good Events?"

Tags: single-word-requests

I have an opportunity to make a career move but I am struggling with leaving behind a team I enjoy working with and with the vacuum that will exist in my absence.

"Bittersweet" is kind of too weak for this feeling, and "Pyrrhic" is a little closer, but this feeling isn't the result of any action I made.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Nostalgia (-ic) is a possibility "The concourse of depressing symptoms which sometimes arise in persons who are absent from their native country, when they are seized with a longing desire of returning to their home and friends... https://www.etymonline.com/search?q=nostalgia

Comment: Bittersweet is not a weak word. It is pertinent here. Look it up. What did you find?

Comment: @chasly-reinstateMonica Very creative! Strange, I never thought Nostalgia could apply while you're in the present, but it does seem to work.

Comment: Another is *wistful (ness)* or even *regret*.

Comment: But is it the good events that make you sad, or the sad event of leaving, albeit for a good reason? Didn't Juliet say parting was such sweet sorrow?

Comment: It is not clear to me *whose* feeling you want to describe, since you say *"the vacuum that will exist in my absence"*.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like shortcut to me.  Say what you feel. That you enjoyed their camaraderie, and will miss their company.  One word may encapsulate that thought, but writing it out will have more impact on your readers.

Saudade, a borrowed word (from the Portuguese--European) but probably would not be widely understood.  I would not use it.  I cannot think of another.

From the Collins online dictionary:

Saudade
New Word Suggestion
this Portuguese word “refers to the feeling of longing for something or someone that you love and which is lost.”
Eg:Fado music, a type of mournful singing, relates to saudade.

Comment: Very nice, that is along the lines of what I was looking for. I'm not looking to express these feelings to anyone, I was just curious if there was an exotic word to describe this feeling that I could maybe put in my journal to look back on many years later.